# C# Control Parent

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, parent

I have a winform project with a tabcontrol and several tabpages.

Within each tabpage there is some unique panel controls.  However, when the user interacts with the form in each tab page, I want a generic picturebox to show.  So I don't want to create a new picturebox for each tabpage, rather show the same one.  Which control should I therefore have as a parent to the picturebox, and how can I change the parent once I drag the control onto the form?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a panel to each tab page then you can set the respective panel as parent on the selected tab page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form has to be the parent.  Which is not so easy to get done in the designer, the tab page will suck it in every opportunity it gets.  One thing you can do is put it to the left of the tab control and move it in place by changing its Location property in the form's constructor, after the InitializeComponent() call

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Left = tabControl1.Left + 15;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Can I then change the location of the panel, when it's time to display it?

Comment: Erm, you can change it whenever you want to.  Doing it early makes sense, it doesn't have to be visible.

Comment: Yep, sorry Hans.  I initially mis-understood.  Thanks.